# How do I import a minecraft rig into my scene?

Tags: rigging, import, linked-data

So I downloaded this [minecraft rig by: VMComix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8siGDupj6Sw) and I was wondering how I can import it into my scene that I created. I tried file, append. But the rig has so many parts, I just don't know what to do, or how to import it!

Answer (score 1):

You can also append Groups. So if you first Group all your parts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and name them you will then be able to navigate to this Group using the file browser when you Append.

Immediately after you create a Group you will be given a chance to name it in the Operator Panel on the left side of your 3D Viewport. If you don't see your Tool Shelf which contains the Operator Panel, you probably just need to press <kbd>T</kbd> while your cursor is inside the 3D Viewport to make it appear.

[image: Naming a new group]

If you later need to browse your groups, you can do it in the Outliner. Double-clicking on the Group's name will allow you to rename it.

[image: Browse or rename Groups from the Outliner]

To see if an object is in a Group, or to add it to or remove it from a Group, you can go to the Object Context to manage this. You can rename groups from here as well.

[image: Modify an Object's Group status]

Comment: Could you dumb it down a bit for me, I'm somewhat new to blender

Comment: When you click 'Append' in the menu, you are taken to a file browser. Within that file browser you will choose  a .blend file. Then you are presented with a list of folders representing the contents of that .blend file. If the .blend file you want to append has a group in it, one of the folders in the list will be named Group. So navigate into that folder, select your Group by its name, and Append it. This means you need to have first grouped your Minecraft rig parts in the .blend you want to Append. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks I got it I just had to append the group... Wow that was easy thanks for letting me know

Comment: Good, I'm glad you got it sorted out! Would you mind marking my answer as accepted, since it helped you solve your problem?